# Is there any way to optimize this MongoDB query for pagination in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization, pagination

I am paginating through a very large collection of documents. I was wondering if this an efficient means of pagination in mongoDB using _id's. My concern is that every time I make the query the entire collection of id's would need to get sorted before a result could be returned. I saw this document on optimizing queries with indexes, but would this apply to me since Im querying on _id which I would've thought is already indexed?

Pagination function:

```
function paginateDocs(currId, docsPerPage) {
  const query = currId ? { _id: { $gt: currId } } : {};
  const queryOptions = { limit: usersPerPage, sort: '_id' };
  return mongo.find(query, queryOptions).toArray();
}
```

Comment: It should pick up the default index `{_id: 1}`, and look for docs in the `>currId` range of the btree. Can you paste output of `mongo.explain(1).find(query, options)`

Comment: I would not be able to perform this in production environment so Im assuming this wouldn't be useful anymore right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor.hint(index) where you can define index as what all indexes on which you want to sort on. Refer to this link->
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/

Comment: Why would I want to override the default index though? Isn't it indexed by default on _id?

Comment: Yeah ok so what you can do is since sorting operation itself is very heavy for you as you have so much documents. You can try keeping _ids in redis which has data structure store, used as database, cache. This will make your query much faster.

Comment: This link will give you more info on redis-